# ffmpeg - HLS live streaming programmatically

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg 3.4 version source code on android. I try to use it to muxer audio/video element stream as m3u8 output and with below options:

```
    int num = av_opt_set_from_string(outputFormatContext->priv_data,
         "hls_list_size=6;start_number=1;hls_wrap=10;hls_time=10;  hls_segment_size=500000;",NULL,"=",";");
    if (num < 0) {
        LOGI("av_opt_set_from_string return error (0x%X) %d",num,num);
    }
```

It works but the output only one file (e.g. test1.ts) and after close the instance, it will generate a m3u8 file as below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:52
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:51.600000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:47199280@0
test1.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

But if I run below command from terminal:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -codec copy -hls_time 10 test.m3u8
```

It will generate ts segments (10 seconds) correctly:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.666667,
test1.ts
#EXTINF:10.666667,
test2.ts
#EXTINF:10.666667,
test3.ts
#EXTINF:10.666667,
test4.ts
#EXTINF:9.633333,
test5.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

How to make my program generate ts segements as a live streaming source?

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `hls_segment_size=500000`
decrease your segment size.